# Visualization of the Recaman Sequence

Tags: javascript, algorithm, processing, p5.js

I saw a video about the Recaman Sequence by Numberphile. If you don't know the algorithm you can look at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGC5TdIiT9U or this one: https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2018/07/09/the-oeis-and-the-recaman-sequence/

I wrote a little piece of software with Processing and p5.js to visualize the sequence. My algorithm makes steps in which the next hop gets defined and then I try to draw a semicircle from the previous point to the new point. My problem is that the current semicircle disappears when the next is drawn. I want all of the semicircles to remain visible.

Here is the link to CodePen where you can see my Code and the Output: https://codepen.io/stefan_coffee/pen/QBBKgp

```js
let S = [];
let count = 0;
let active_num = 0;

function setup() {

}

function draw() {
   createCanvas(600, 400);
   background(50, 50, 50);

   for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      step();
      drawStep();
   }
}  


function drawStep() {
  var x =  (S[S.indexOf(active_num)-1] + active_num ) /2;
  var y = height / 2;
  var w = active_num - S[S.indexOf(active_num)-1];
  var h = w;

  if (count % 2 == 0) {
    stroke(255);
    noFill();
    arc(x, y, w, h, PI, 0)
  } else {
    stroke(255);
    noFill();
    arc(x, y, w, h, 0, PI);
  }
}

function step() {
  count++;
  S.push(active_num);
  console.log('active_num: ' + active_num +'  count: ' + count + '  ' + S);
  if (S.indexOf(active_num - count) > 0) {
    active_num += count;
  } else {
    if (active_num - count <= 0) {
      active_num += count;
    } else {
      active_num -= count;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I want my output to look something like this: [image: Visualization using ellipses]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While `draw` is called continuously in every frame, `setup` is only called once at startup.

Create the canvas only once and clear the back ground only once at startup. This will cause that semicircles continuously  added to the canvas, with out clearing the semicircles  from the previous frames:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 400);
    background(50, 50, 50);
}

function draw() {

   for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      step();
      drawStep();
   }
}
```

---

Further there is an issue in your algorithm. When you search for the index of `active_num`, you may not find `active_num` in the array `S`, because it is not added yet, but it will be added in the next loop. See `step`, where `active_num` is added to `S` at the begin of the function, but increment later.

In the function `drawStep` you want to read the last element of the array, which you can get by:

```
var prev_num = S[count-1];
```

The relevant values for the next `arc` are the last element of the array `S` and `active_num`.

To solve the issue, you may change the code like this:

```
function drawStep() {
   var prev_num = S[count-1];

   var x = (prev_num + active_num) /2;
   var y = height / 2;
   var w = abs(active_num - prev_num);
   var h = w;

   stroke(255);
   noFill();
   arc(x, y, w, h, (count % 2 == 0) ? 0 : PI, (count % 2 == 0) ? PI : TWO_PI);
}
```

---

Note, you can completely skip the loop in the function `draw`, so you can better "see" the "animation":

```
function draw() {
   step();
   drawStep();
}
```

and you can manually set the frames per second by [`frameRate`](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html):

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 400);
    background(50, 50, 50);
    frameRate(20);
}
```

If you would scale the size of the semicircles, then the result may look like this:

```
function drawStep() {
   var scale    = 10;
   var prev_num = scale * S[count-1];
   var num      = scale * active_num;

   var x = (prev_num + num) /2;
   var y = height / 2;
   var w = abs(num - prev_num);
   var h = w;

   stroke(255);
   noFill();
   arc(x, y, w, h, (count % 2 == 0) ? 0 : PI, (count % 2 == 0) ? PI : TWO_PI);
}
```

[image: preview]

```js
let S = [];
let count = 0;
let active_num = 0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 400);
    background(50, 50, 50);
    frameRate(20);
}

function draw() {
   step();
   drawStep();
}  

function drawStep() {
   var scale    = 10;
   var prev_num = scale * S[count-1];
   var num      = scale * active_num;

   var x = (prev_num + num) /2;
   var y = height / 2;
   var w = abs(num - prev_num);
   var h = w;

   stroke(255);
   noFill();
   arc(x, y, w, h, (count % 2 == 0) ? 0 : PI, (count % 2 == 0) ? PI : TWO_PI);
}

function step() {
   count++;
   S.push(active_num);
   console.log('active_num: ' + active_num +'  count: ' + count + '  ' + S);
   if (S.indexOf(active_num - count) > 0) {
      active_num += count;
   } else {
      if (active_num - count <= 0) {
         active_num += count;
      } else {
         active_num -= count;
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, as others have pointed out, you want to avoid asking p5.js to redraw the canvas from scratch every iteration.  While we're at it, we'll drop the frame rate to something slow (1 per second) to prevent the browser going crazy.  So, make the following changes to `setup()`:

```
function setup() {
  // Move these two lines from draw():
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  background(50, 50, 50);
  // Add this line to slow things down
  frameRate(1);
}
```

Next, let's get rid of the loop where we call `draw()` and `drawStep()` repeatedly.  p5.js will already be calling `draw()` repeatedly, there's no need for us to repeatedly call these functions.  Let's also make the animation stop after a certain number of steps:

```
function draw() {
    step();
    drawStep();

    if (count >= 20) {
        noLoop();
    }
}
```

So, we make these changes to your code, and what happens?  We see some semicircles, but not many.

To investigate why, take a look at the first line of your `drawStep` function:

```
var x =  (S[S.indexOf(active_num)-1] + active_num ) /2;
```

I think you are intending `S[S.indexOf(active_num)-1]` to be the previous number in the sequence, but this expression will not work as you expect:

- If `active_num` appears somewhere else within `S` (this does happen: 42 is the first number to appear twice), then `S[S.indexOf(active_num)-1]` will return the number that was before the first occurrence of `active_num`, not the current occurrence.
- If `active_num` doesn't occur anywhere else within `S`, `S.indexOf(active_num)` will be `-1`, and hence `S[S.indexOf(active_num)-1]` evaluates to `S[-2]`, which is `undefined`.

In the first case you will get arbitrary incorrect semicircles, in the second you will get nothing.

The previous number in the sequence is in fact the last one in `S`, and you can get that using `S[S.length-1]`.  So, let's replace `S.indexOf(active_num)` with `S.length` in both places it occurs in `drawStep()`:

```
   var x =  (S[S.length-1] + active_num ) /2;
   var y = height / 2;
   var w = active_num - S[S.length-1];
   var h = w;
```

Finally, I'd suggest replacing the line:

```
    if (S.indexOf(active_num - count) > 0) {
```

with

```
    if (S.indexOf(active_num - count) >= 0) {
```

The intention of this line is to say 'if `active_num - count` is already in `S` then ...', but if `active_num - count` is zero, `S.indexOf(active_num - count)` will be zero because `0` is in `S` at index 0.  It happens that the `else` block correctly handles the case where `active_num - count` is zero, so you don't have a bug, but it's worth being aware that `S.indexOf` can return `0` to indicate an element is in `S`.

Finally, you may want to consider scaling the drawing up to match the image you included in your question.  That should just be a case of multiplying the `x` offset and the width and height of your semi-circular arcs by a scale factor.  I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 2):

The first step to solving the problem in this:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  noLoop();
}
```

By default `draw` is used to draw an animation, and it is called repeatedly, and is the reason you're seeing flickering shapes. [`noLoop()`](https://p5js.org/examples/structure-no-loop.html) causes `draw` to be called only once.

Even with this change, I couldn't get your code working.

Comment: But I want to do this as an animation. Is there an alternative?